# laravel access model properties

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am looking for solution how to access eloquent model items by 'alias' field. 
There is no problem accessing items by 'id'. But building a custom query I find myself unable to access item properties.

This piece of code works perfect

```
$cat = Category::find(1);
return $cat->title;
```

But if I am querying items with any other argument - properties are inaccessible

This code

```
$cat = Category::where('alias','=','vodosnab')->get();
return $cat->title;
```

throws an exception

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$title
```

Could you please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already got the answer but here are some insights, when you use `get()` or `all()`, it returns a collection of model objects, which is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`, so here you'll get a `Collection` object

```
$cat = Category::where('alias','=','vodosnab')->get();
```

Now, you can use, `$cat->first()` to get the first item (`Category Model`) from the collection and you may also use `$cat->last()` to get the last item or `$cat->get(1)` to get the second item from the collection. These methods are available in the `Collection` object.

Using the `first()` method like `Category::where('alias','=','vodosnab')->first();` will return you only a single (the first mathing item) model which is an instance of your `Category` model. So, use `all()` or `get()` to get a collection of model objects and you can loop through the collection like:

```
foreach(Category::all() as $cat) { // or Category::get()
    $cat->propertyName;
}
```

Or you may use:

```
$categories = Category::where('alias','=','vodosnab')->get();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $category->propertyName;
}
```

Also, you may use:

```
$categories = Category::where('alias','=','vodosnab')->get();
$firstModel = $categories->first();
$lastModel = $categories->last();
$thirdModel = $categories->get(2); // 0 is first
```

If you need to get only one then you may directly use:

```
$category = Category::where('alias','=','vodosnab')->first();
$category->fieldname;
```

Remember that, if you use `get()` you'll get a collection of `Model` objects even if there is only one record available in the database. So, in your example here:

```
$cat = Category::where('alias','=','vodosnab')->get();
return $cat->title;
```

You are trying to get a property from the `Collection` object and if you want you may use:

```
$cat = Category::where('alias','=','vodosnab')->get();
return $cat->first()->title; // first item/Category model's title
return $cat->last()->title; // last item/Category model's title
return $cat->get(0)->title; // first item/Category model's title
```

You may read [this article](http://heera.it/extend-laravel-eloquent-collection-object) written on `Laravel`'s `Collection` object.

Answer (score 5):

`get()` returns a `Collection` of items. You probably need `first()` that returns a single item.